# Evaluate $ \int_1^2(x-1)\sqrt{2-x}\,dx $ using Change of Variables

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$ \int_1^2(x-1)\sqrt{2-x}\,dx $$

I think the answer should be 4/15, but I keep dropping a sign somewhere

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. This information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=2-x$, so $x=2-u$ and $dx=-du$.

Then $\displaystyle\int_1^2(x-1)\sqrt{2-x}dx=\int_1^0(1-u)\sqrt{u}(-1)du=\int_0^1(u^{1/2}-u^{3/2})du$

$\displaystyle=\left[\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}-\frac{2}{5}u^{5/2}\right]_0^1=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{5}=\frac{4}{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $2-x=t^2$. Then $dx=-2tdt$.

$$\int_1^2(1-t^2)\cdot t\cdot(-2t)\cdot dt=2\int_1^2t^2(t^2-1)dt$$

Comment: (I think you want to change the limits of integration as well.)